# Can I get ip address inside my docker container?

Tags: docker, ip-address

How to get container ip address inside this container?

'docker inspect $hostname ...' not suitable, because I don't share /var/run/docker.sock host file to container.

Comment: For what usecase? If it is for a server, you'd usually just look at the local IP for incoming requests.

Comment: I will send ip to another container (example, nginx) and create upstream (redirect subdomain http request) from nginx to first container.

Comment: I think normally you'd do that with linking? Like when you start your nginx box, you specify `--link firstcontainer:firstcontainer` and then in nginx, you can actually just proxy to a hostname `firstcontainer` because the linking will automatically set up DNS to resolve it to the firstcontainer IP.

Comment: I can't link, because first I run nginx container. It seems strange, but in my case it's correct action.

Comment: Cool, just wanted to be sure there was a reason.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

As the IP address is in the first line of /etc/hosts, you can do in a container  the awk command that prints the first word of the first line of /etc/hosts

```
$ awk 'END{print $1}' /etc/hosts
172.17.0.14
```

Comment: This seems to no longer be true. In a container on docker-engine 1.10.3, /etc/hosts has my ip address as the last line, and the loopback as the first line.

Comment: Now `awk 'END{print $1}' /etc/hosts`seems to do the job

Comment: Not necessarily true and completely unsafe

Comment: awk is overkill, maybe a simple sed command fits the need (removing spaces I guess?) `sed -i 's/[ \t]*$//' "$1"`

Answer (score 126):

I can find the IP address with

```
hostname -i
```

Of course, that may not be completely accurate if there is more than one interface.

**Edit**

Note: According to the *hostname* man page, `hostname -i` uses DNS to resolve the ip address, where `hostname -I` displays all the addresses except loopback, does not depend on DNS, and is recommended.

In all my Docker containers, `-i` and `-I` return the same results (but this is not the case on my desktop).

Comment: To be more precise: `hostname -i | awk '{print $1}'` because there is a trailing space (and may be more than one IP)

Comment: @RomualdBrunet it should be `hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'` because `-i` gives single ip where `-I` gives multiple (if present)

Comment: When I connect a docker container to two networks, `hostname -i` and `hostname -I` both return `172.18.0.2 172.19.0.2` (but `hostname -I` does return a trailing space). I think the behavior of `hostname -i` depends on how dns is configured.

Answer (score 5):

Why not something as simple as:

```
grep "`hostname`" /etc/hosts|awk '{print $1}'
```

or

```
grep "$HOSTNAME" /etc/hosts|awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: This will return multiple IP addresses if your hostname happens to be a substring of some other hostname.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you can use the linux program `ifconfig` to get IP addresses and other networking details. Your container may not have it, in which case you'll need to install it via `apt-get` or `yum` or your distro's package manager. A basic pipeline to get the IP address would be

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr:" | cut -d : -f 2 | cut -d " " -f 1
```

Comment: A container will not necessarily have an eth0 interface.

Comment: A container will also not necessarily have `ifconfig` installed.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to my problem:

```
/sbin/ip route|awk '/scope/ { print $9 }'
```

It's print something like: '172.17.0.135'

Answer (score 1):

You could also look for a line in /etc/hosts that ends with a container id and print the first field:

```
sed -n 's/^\([0-9\.]*\)[[:blank:]]*[0-9a-f]\{12,\}$/\1/p' /etc/hosts
```

I'd use awk, but standard awk in dedian:jessie doesn't support regex quantifiers like `{12,}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use `ip` rather than `ifconfig`, on Linux you can do:

```
ip addr | grep inet | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```

This simply gets **all** of the IP addresses and interfaces, searches only for those starting with `inet` and returns only the 3rd column.

As a nice side-effect, this includes the subnet mask, too! (e.g. `172.17.0.2/16`)

If you don't want the subnet mask, you can use:

```
ip addr | grep inet | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | tr -d '/'
```

**NOTE:** This shows **ALL** of the IPs in the container. You can use `awk` or `sed` to remove `127.0.0.1/16` and other unwanted IPs. :)

Answer (score 1):

This may work on some containers if it has the "hostname" command.

**docker ps**      to get the (container id)

**docker exec -it** (container id) **hostname -i**

Comment: Good guess, but no.  The question explicitly states that they can't run the docker command inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM alpine

# Upgrade grep so that it supports -Po flags
RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade grep

ENV IPADDRESS "ip a show eth0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+'"
```

Answer (score 0):

linux ip command is helpful

ip a s eth0 | grep -E -o 'inet [0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}' | cut -d' ' -f2

Answer (score -2):

The older answers have been very helpful.

This worked for me; it appends the export command into the `.bashrc` file in the home (`~/`) directory inside the container

```
# Add this line to Dockerfile
RUN echo 'export CONTAINER_IP="$(hostname -i)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Now you can access the computed value of `CONTAINER_IP` environment variable inside the container.