# Get Docker container IP within a .net core application

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, consul

What is the best way to get the current docker container IP address within the container itself using `.net core`?

I try to register my container to a `Consul` server which is hosted on the Docker host (not as a container) and I need to get the container IP address on startup to make the registration. Because the IP addresses change on any container startup I can't just hard-code it into the `appsettings.json`. I followed this [tutorial](https://cecilphillip.com/using-consul-for-service-discovery-with-asp-net-core/). And when it comes to this section:

```
// Get server IP address
var features = app.Properties["server.Features"] as FeatureCollection;
var addresses = features.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();
var address = addresses.Addresses.First();

// Register service with consul
var uri = new Uri(address);
var registration = new AgentServiceRegistration()
{
     ID = $"{consulConfig.Value.ServiceID}-{uri.Port}",
     Name = consulConfig.Value.ServiceName,
     Address = $"{uri.Scheme}://{uri.Host}",
     Port = uri.Port,
     Tags = new[] { "Students", "Courses", "School" }
};
```

The received `address` contains only the loopback address and not the actual container address (as seen from outside - the host where `Consul` is running). I already tried to use the `HttpContext` (which is `null` in the startup class) and the `IHttpContextAccessor` which also does not contain anything at this time.

---

**EDIT**: This is a part of my `appsettings.json`:

```
  "ServiceRegistry": {
    "Uri": "http://172.28.112.1:8500",
    "Name": "AuthServiceApi",
    "Id": "auth-service-api-v1",
    "ContainerAddress": "http://<CONTAINER_IP/DNS>",
    "Checks": [
      {
        "Service": "/health",
        "Timeout": 5,
        "Interval":  10 
      }
    ], 
    "Tags": [ "Auth", "User" ]
  }
```

The `Uri` is the one from my host system and I managed to register the service in Consul. The missing part is the `<CONTAINER_IP/DNS>` which is needed for Consul to perform some checks for that particular container. Here I need either the IP of the container or the DNS on which it is accessible from the host system. I know that this IP will switch with every container starup and it's in the settings only for demonstration purpose (I'm happy if I can get the IP at startup time).

Comment: May I ask why you not like using docker hostnames? this way you don't have to bother about internal IP addresses at all, as docker acts as DHCP server and (by default) the hostname of a container is it's name. so a http://containername/ will get you to one of the containers running in docker

Comment: Also you should iterate over the `addresses.Addresses` property. You are just picking the first, there may be other more suitable ones

Comment: @Tseng: Could I also use it's container_id as hostname because I set `container_name` in the `docker-compose` and also use replicas (not sure how this will work together at all)? I'm quite new to docker and was not aware there are such methods. I appreciate other solutions that do not rely on IPs :-)

Comment: This could be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670495/can-i-get-ip-address-inside-my-docker-container

Comment: Also remember, in a Docker Compose context, Compose will tell Docker each container can be reached under its key in the `docker-compose.yml` file, which will be different from the container name or the container-private hostname.

Comment: Outside the Docker container the Docker-internal IP addresses are basically useless, and if you're using Consul in this context what you should register is the host's IP address (it is one valid if dated way to build multi-host Docker setups).  You'd have to pass that in externally, or have Consul do HTTP-based discovery on its own and not depend on containers to register themselves.

Comment: @DavidMaze: Thanks for your suggestions. I also made an edit for the question. I have no problems to call the container from another container with it's DNS (e.g. `com.company.auth`) but it's not working from the host. On the host I need to use the IP - which I get from `docker inspect <conatiner_name>` - but I like to get the IP of the container within the container itself so I can feed it to Consul.

Comment: You never want to use the container’s internal IP address, even from the host, and looking up the address to register it in Consul isn’t useful.  From the host you can use the host’s IP address (or in this very specific case `localhost`) to reach a `docker run -p` published port on a container.

Comment: @DavidMaze: I tried your suggestion to access the container with `http://localhost`. This is not working and there seem to be problems with "Windows containers" (https://blog.sixeyed.com/published-ports-on-windows-containers-dont-do-loopback/). I haven't figured out if this finally solved but it seems that it's not (I did some tests and troubleshooting as suggested in open GIT Issues without success). I also use `docker-compose` and not `docker run`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, I got it working and it was much easier than I thought.

```
var name = Dns.GetHostName(); // get container id
var ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(name).AddressList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

With the `container_id/name` I could get the IP with an easy compare if it's an IP4 address. I then can use this address and pass it to Consul. The health checks can now successfully call the container with it's IP from the outside host.

I'm still not 100% satisfied with the result because it relies on the "first" valid IP4 address in the `AddressList` (currently, there are no more so I got this going for me). Any better / more generic solution would still be welcome.

Comment: Hi can you post you code? .. where do you set your var ip? do you use it  here?  var registration = new AgentServiceRegistration()
            {
                ID = _registrationID,
                Name = _consulConfig.Value.ServiceName,
                Address = $"{uri.Host}", // <-- IP ?????
                Port = uri.Port,
                Tags = _consulConfig.Value.Tags.ToArray()
            };

Comment: I ve upvote your anwer cause it give me in the right way .. but plz .. need little bit more help ;)

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi: I'll answer you tomorrow. Not in town nor access to my repo atm.

Comment: I've DONE IT !!.. now i'm tryng to deploy it on k8 .. REALLY REALLY thnx for your HELP!!

Comment: The most reliable way to get a pod IP address is to ask k8s itself. You can add an env var to the container spec and read the value in the app https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev: I'm not using Kubernetes.

Comment: @Alex why not use just the hostname? I was stuck with scale services, but the hostname was enough to register the services.

Comment: @Zachdev: In my case I needed the IP beacuse hostname lookup was not possible from outside docker (Host -> Container). I don't know if this is working correctly now but it was not possible then.

Comment: Does the code give IP address of the container or the host?

Comment: @VinitDivekar: Container

Answer (score 0):

I too had a requirement lyk above where I had to spin up a docker container and get the container IP address and save to some directory all using c#(.net core) (this concept will work with other programming lang as well). Below is the piece of code to achieve that. Please leave a up vote if u like, comment if u didn't.

**Note: This method is pretty reliable as it will get the ip-address of the particular container you want.**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Getting Container IP...");
          //This command returns back ip address of the required container.
          string inspectCommand = string.Concat("inspect -f ", "\"{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}\"", " container ID/Name");
          //The command is appended with string 'docker' as all docker commans starts with it
          var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("docker", $"{inspectCommand}");

          processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
          processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
          processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
          processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;'

          using (var process = new Process())
          {
            process.StartInfo = processInfo;
            var started = process.Start();

              StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
              //to remove any unwanted char if appended 
              ip = Regex.Replace(reader.ReadToEnd(), @"\t|\n|\r", "");
              if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
              {
                Console.WriteLine($"Unable to get ip of the container");
                Environment.Exit(1);
              }
              Console.WriteLine($"Azurite conatainer is listening @ {ip}");

              Environment.Exit(1);
           }}
```

Comment: This gets the container IP from _outside_ the container. The original question asks how to get the container IP from _inside_ the container.

Comment: @x0n If you read the original question it says How to get the running container IP in a .net core application. So my solution does exactly that. Plz read the code properly before giving thums down

Comment: I did read it -- I think this is a language/context issue. The OP wants to know a container IP from code running inside the _same_ container; this is proven by the answer they accepted (which only works from inside the same container). Your method is calling docker inspect, which will not be available inside the container. I downvoted because your answer does not answer the question.