# Expose ssh tunnel to remote mysql server to other container?

Tags: mysql, docker, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I want to use Docker for local web development and followed different tutorials for that. We can access the mysql server only via a ssh tunnel.
I wanted to put that part into a special container, only responsible for setting up the ssh tunnel to the mysql server and then other containers can connect to that container as if it was a local mysql server. I thought that makes more sense than every container connecting via ssh themselves.
Or would that be a better idea?

I came across this Docker-image: https://hub.docker.com/r/dogstudio/remote-ssh but could not get it working for me so I tried it by myself.

So far I managed to create a Docker container and inside its bash shell I would call `ssh user@example.com -4 -L 33306:127.0.0.1:3306 -N` and afterwards be able to connect to the remote mysql server via `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 33306 -u user -p`.

I then go inside the bash of the other Docker container (`php`) and try to call `mysql -h ssh_mysql -P 33306 -u user -p`.
Unfortunately I always get the error `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ssh_mysql' (111 "Connection refused")`.

I tried out quite a lot, for example what was explained here: https://superuser.com/questions/588591/how-to-make-ssh-tunnel-open-to-public but probably I did something wrong or misunderstood something.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2.1"

services:
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx/
        ports:
            - 80:80
        links:
            - php
        volumes:
            - "${PROJECT_ROOT}:/var/www/html:ro"
        networks:
            - server
        depends_on:
            - php

    php:
        build: ./php/
        expose:
            - 9000
        links:
            - ssh_mysql
        volumes:
            - "${PROJECT_ROOT}:/var/www/html"
            - "${SSH_FOLDER}:/root/.ssh"
        networks:
            - database
            - server
        depends_on:
            - ssh_mysql

    ssh_mysql:
        build: ./mysql/
        expose:
            - 33306
        networks:
            - database
        volumes:
            - "${SSH_FOLDER}/id_rsa:/root/.ssh"

volumes:
    data:

networks:
    database:
    server:
```

Comment: "Unfortunately I am then not able to connect to the mysql server from another container, I always get the error..." What actual command are you running at this point, or what are you specifically doing which fails? What specific error message are you getting? How are you specifying the hostname and port which you're trying to connect to?

Comment: For anyone who is interested in this question: it seems like opening the ssh-tunnel with `ssh user@host -4 -L 3307:0.0.0.0:3306 -N -g` (`0.0.0.0` and the `-g` flag) made the difference... then I was able to call from other container `mysql -h "IP-address of container" -u mysql_user -p -P 3307`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like opening the ssh-tunnel with

```
ssh user@host -4 -L 3307:0.0.0.0:3306 -N -g
```

(especially the `-g` flag)

made the difference...

Then I was able to access the MySQL DB on the remote server via the SSH tunnel of the other container by calling:

```
$ mysql -h ssh_mysql -u mysql_user -p -P 3307
```

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is that you bind SSH tunnel to 127.0.0.1 so to localhost and localhost is only for that container with SSH tunnel so you can reach tunnel from within that container but not from others.

To fix that you should do something like described in this post: [Can I get ip address inside my docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670495/can-i-get-ip-address-inside-my-docker-container)

So something like

```
ssh user@example.com -4 -L 33306:$(awk 'END{print $1}' /etc/hosts):3306 -N
```

should do the job.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately if I do this, it is not possible anymore to even connect to the remote mysql server from the same container (now getting there `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.16.3' (115)`) nor from another container (still getting the error `"Connection refused"` as mentioned above)...